# How to pass bind or eval arguments with the client function "OnClientClicking"

Tags: asp.net, eval, bind, onclientclick

I meet about problem to pass arguments to the client-side event `OnClientClicking`.

I tried to use the `String.Format ()` function, but it does not work.

Do you have an idea for a workaround to send parameter linked with `OnClientClicking`?

Code `asp` :

```
<telerik:RadButton ID="bnt_meetingDelete" runat="server" OnClientClicking="<%# string.Format("confirmCallBackFn('{0}');",Eval("MeetingID")) %>" Image-ImageUrl="~/image/icone/delete-icon.png" Image-IsBackgroundImage="true" Width="21" Height="21" telerik:RadButton>
```

Error `IIS`:

```
Parser Error 
Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: The server tag is not well formed.
```

I tried with controller [asp: ImageButton ]. And is the same mistake

Comment: Isn't it normally OnClientClick not OnClientClicking?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change  double quote to single quote from

```
OnClientClicking="<%#string.Format("confirmCallBackFn('{0}');",Eval("MeetingID")) %>"
```

to

```
OnClientClicking='<%#string.Format("confirmCallBackFn('{0}');",Eval("MeetingID")) %>'
```

Or remove your `string.Format` and use like this

```
OnClientClicking='<%# "confirmCallBackFn("+ Eval("MeetingID") + ");" %>'
```

Comment: I had to escape the quotes inside the string.format string with slashes and use double quotes `confirmCallBackFn(\"{0}\")` and to get double quotes inside that javascript string I had to triple escape them like so `"return confirm(\"Delete \\\"{0}\\\"?\")"`

Answer (score 1):

try `OnClientClicking='<%# Eval("MeetingID", "confirmCallBackFn({0})") %>'`

Answer (score 0):

Use this format

> OnClientClick='<%# "text1" + Eval("value") + "text2"  %>'

Make you you escape the `\"` correctly for it to work correctly:

```
OnClientClick='<%# "return confirm(\"Are you sure you want to unlock this user " + Eval("Lockout") + "?\");" %>'/>
```

It will be look like this after it rendered:

```
onclick="return confirm("Are you sure you want to unlock this user True?");"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just sharing, Framework version 4.6.1.

OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("return confirm(Hello team: ""{0}"");",Eval("Name")) %>'