# OnClientClick parameterized from code behind variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am not sure what my problem is because when i click the button no error in console and the javascript is not triggered.

asp

```
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='<%# "show("+Eval("I") +");" %>' />
```

server side

```
public partial class _Default : Page
{
    public string ClientID = "1";

    public string I = "2";
    public string J = "3";

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Page.DataBind();
    }
}
```

javascript

```
 function show(str) {
            //var str = "test";
            console.log(str);
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(str);
        }
```

I've been referring to below post, but I still couldnt figure it out... will someone help?

[How to pass bind or eval arguments with the client function "OnClientClicking"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17525539/how-to-pass-bind-or-eval-arguments-with-the-client-function-onclientclicking)

Comment: Are you DataBinding the page? `Page.DataBind()`?

Comment: I dont have Page.DataBind() at my code behind, but when I put it in Page_Load, it run into execution error saying System.InvalidOperationException: 'Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be used in the context of a databound control.'

Comment: Instead of doing Eval("I") do just `I`

Comment: Thanks! I've modified to below and it worked, together with Page.DataBind.

Please post as answer and I will accept. :-)

  <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick='<%# String.Format("show({0});", I)%>' />